# "SIM Tool Kit: Error in application" pop-up always shows on Lenovo Vibe K5

Tags: sim-card, system-error

I have a Lenovo Vibe K5. The phone screen always shows a pop-up message saying:

> **SIM Tool Kit**
>
> Error in application

[image: screenshot]

How to fix this issue?

Comment: please try this, go to settings->apps and clear cache and data of sim toolkit app. OR check for any settings available to block notification(pop-up) of that app.

Answer (score 0):

Check if both SIMs are activated or not. If not, kindly recharge and activate it. The pop up will not come.

Ex. I got this error due to Airtel SIM and my SIM's incoming outgoing was already stopped. I also got the same error, also tried all things posted on internet and YouTube. I recharged RC 35 and it automatically resolved.